# Boolean regex AND with multiple capture groups in Javascript not working

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm attempting to capture 3 mandatory elements of a URL with multiple capture groups in Javascript Regex, but for the life of me I can't get it to work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
https://bobsfurniture.com/chairs/COZRdyga141uWgV5w/purchase/?itemIds=qUUWmD7eRaCz9wnJEGLZQQ
```

I'm trying to capture the domain, the product category (chairs), and the purchase. This is my capture grouping:

```
(?=.*bobsfurniture)(?=.*chairs)(?=.*purchase)
```

Comment: You can always plug your regexp into one of the many websites out there that validates and explains the syntax.  Other than that, my first thought was the `?` might need to be escaped. Edit: though I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that.  Edit2: ah, positive look ahead

Comment: Instead of regex you can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) classes to parse URLs.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/VCXuIw/1  seems to match without the `?=` in there

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to match the whole url, only if all three capturing groups (which are actually positive lookahead assertions, but the right tool to use here). If you take your regex and simply add `.*` at the end, it seems to do, what you want it to. You can see the explanation beautifully on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/VCXuIw/2

Comment: `(?=...)` are not capturing groups, they are positive lookaheads that do not consume any text. Check a [regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/A32rjS/1), it might help.